# Custom Page Module with existing theme template?

Tags: module, theme, template, xml

Is there a way to use a template from a third-party theme, that is already installed, with a newly created custom page module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the phtml template file.

**Assumption**:

- `TuVan/blue` is a third-party theme, it has declared a block with a phtml template file in the layout `app/design/frontend/TuVan/blue/Magento_Theme/default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

- Your custom module is Andersen_CustomPage.

**Solution**:

Step 1:
In this case, the phtml template file declared using for `Magento_Theme` module, so you have to add dependency `Magento_Theme` module to your module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Andersen_CustomPage" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Step 2. You can use the template from `TuVan/blue` theme by declaring a block in layout in your module and assigning the template's file path to that block, for example
`app/code/Andersen/CustomPage/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="top.copyright" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 3: Clear cache, done.

Comment: Thanks. 

How would this work with routing? Wouldn't using the catalog_product_view.xml layout break it?

Comment: No, it can work for all layouts, catalog_product_view is an example. For example, if you want to make a change to the catalog product page, you should use `catalog_product_view.xml`, if you want to make a change to the catalog category page, you should use `catalog_category_view.xml`, so on.

Comment: Let's give it a try, if this answer works as your expected, please mark it as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.

Comment: But doesn't routing require a layout of with a name of [module_name]_[controller]_[action].xml?

Comment: You are lost. In this original question, you asked for using an existing phtml template in a custom module. I already say that change can be applied to all pages, so you can apply it to [module_name]_[controller]_[action].xml. Back to your Routing question (in another question), I'll answer the routing there.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it as a child in your custom page via xml.

Comment: How can you do that?